# using data-transformation for the data which has too many zeros

Tags: anova, data-transformation

I do a ANOVA, when I do the normality test, the data has too many zeros, how to make the data to normality using the transformation?
[image]

Comment: Welcome to CV. You might want to consider expanding the question from asking about a transformation to asking about more appropriate models for zero-heavy data.

Comment: Thank you!@DJohnson, so I can't do ANOVA with the data?

Answer (score 6):

First, the *data* in an ANOVA does not have to be normal.  The errors (as estimated by the residuals) do.

However, when the dependent variable has a lot of 0's, the residuals will not be normal.

Second, no transformation  will get rid of excess 0s.  You can't use ANOVA on these data.  You should use a zero inflated regression such as zero inflated Poisson or zero inflated negative binomial.